# Trying to target a specific image in a jsp foreach loop

Tags: jsp, foreach, jsp-tags

I have a list of images in an array list:

```
<c:forEach items="${articleContent.articleMediaList}" var="gridImage" varStatus="imgCount">
     <img src="${imagePath}${gridImage.image"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Right now this is printing out all the images. I just want it to print out the third image. Also, how could I get it to print out a range of images say 1 to 3?

Comment: use [varStatus](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html)
to get the index [c:forEach varStatus properties](http://www.bmchild.com/2012/03/jstl-cforeach-varstatus-properties.html).

Comment: How would I be able to operate on every third image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use imgCount.count or imgCount.index for getting numbering and after that you can handle it.